# Issues while upgrading from grails 2.x to grails 3.x

Tags: grails

I am trying to upgraade my app from grails 2.4 to 3.2.6. While doing so i am trying to resolve the dependencies in build.gradle.

I am getting the following compilation error
/Users/shiraz/Project/upgrade1/intl_upgrade/src/main/groovy/com/care/util/HttpUtil.groovy: 24: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest
 @ line 24, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest

### I seemingly have added the required dependency in build.gradle

dependencies {

```
compile "org.grails:grails-web-common:2.5.0"
```

but still no affect as the error still shows up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Shiraz

Answer (score 0):

Regarding docs [GrailsWebRequest](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsWebRequest.html) was deprecated so you should use [GrailsWebRequest](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/api/org/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsWebRequest.html) instead. (different packages, but the same name don't be confused :) )

Comment: Hi @Kolortnij, your suggestion worked!. I am facing another error as below...^[[1A^[[1m<=------------> 14% EXECUTING^[[m^[[29D^[[1B^[[1A/Users/shiraz/Project/upgrade1/intl_upgrade/grails-app/domain/com/care/CareRegistrationCode.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegistrationCode^[[0K
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegistrationCode
   ^

can you please guide me here

Comment: Try to follow installation guide: https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/v3/index.html